# compare date select from datepicker with values sql table

Tags: jquery, mysql, datepicker

I am new in this. I want to select from a SQL table only the records dating with date select from `datepicker`.

I have the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("#result").text("You selected " + dateText);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form name="form" method="get" action="calendar.php">
  <p>Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker">
  </p>
</form>
```

This shows an `input`, from which I select a date from `datepicker`.
The date selected I want to be a variable that allows me to filter records from SQL table. I can't get the date selected from `input`.

Thanks

I found the solution
Add the code before closing form (/form>)

```
<div id="result"></div>
 <input type="submit" value="Validate" >
```

And then, in calendar.php introduce the code

```
<?php
  $mytext = $_POST['datepicker'];
  echo $mytext;
?>
```

thank you for your time... and ideas :)

Comment: Not sure to understand what you need. Do you want to send the selected date via ajax to your `calendar.php` and display the result in a div each time you change the `datepicker` date ?

Comment: the form element is from the various methods I've  tried, I wan to get the date in a variable php

Comment: What you need is not clear. The onSelect event return the selected Date as String. You can't convert a javascript variable in a php variable. You need to send it using a get or post request to the php page.

Comment: thank you for reponse. I found the solution. I add the code <div id="result"></div>
 <input type="submit" value="Valideaza" >

Answer (score 0):

Where is your "#result"?
You need someone "#result" element, Then it can show your date value.

Or you can change to

```
alert("You selected " + dateText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag anywhere inside body and you will get date which is selected from datepicker.

`<p id="result"></p>`

Comment: thank you for reponse. but how can I put this in a php variable, I've tried some variants, without results...